# BeautifulSoup4: Fail to find 'a' tag with specific href value by find()

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl the realtime Bitcoin-HKD Currency from https://www.coinbase.com/pt-PT/price/ with python3.

The only way I found to locate it specificly in the HTML is by this tage **a** with **href="/pt-PT/price/bitcoin"**

```
    <a href="/pt-PT/price/bitcoin" title="Visite a moeda Bitcoin" data-element-handle="asset-highlight-top-daily-volume" class="Link__A-eh4rrz-0 hfBqui AssetHighlight__StyledLink-sc-1srucyv-1 cbFcph" color="slate">
                               <h2 class="AssetHighlight__Title-sc-1srucyv-2 jmJxYl">Volume mais alto (24 h)</h2>
                               <div class="Flex-l69ttv-0 gaVUrq">
                                  <img src="https://dynamic-assets.coinbase.com/e785e0181f1a23a30d9476038d9be91e9f6c63959b538eabbc51a1abc8898940383291eede695c3b8dfaa1829a9b57f5a2d0a16b0523580346c6b8fab67af14b/asset_icons/b57ac673f06a4b0338a596817eb0a50ce16e2059f327dc117744449a47915cb2.png" alt="Visite a moeda Bitcoin" aria-label="Visite a moeda Bitcoin" loading="lazy" class="AssetHighlight__AssetImage-sc-1srucyv-5 lcjcxh"/>
                                  <div class="Flex-l69ttv-0 kvilOX">
                                     <div class="Flex-l69ttv-0 gTbYCC">
                                        <h3 class="AssetHighlight__SubTitle-sc-1srucyv-3 gdcBEE">Bitcoin</h3>
                                        <p class="AssetHighlight__Price-sc-1srucyv-4 bUAWAG">460 728,81 HK$</p>
```

Here **460 728,81 HK$** is the data wanted.

Thus I applied the following codes:

```
    import bs4

    import urllib.request as req
    url="https://www.coinbase.com/prthe ice/bitcoin/hkd"
    
    request=req.Request(url,headers={
        "user-agent":"..."
        })
    with req.urlopen(request) as response:
        data=response.read().decode("utf-8")
    
    root=bs4.BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")
    secBitcoin=root.find('a',href="/pt-PT/price/bitcoin")
    realtimeCurrency=secBitcoin.find('p')
    print(realtimeCurrency.string)
```

However, it always returns secBitcoin = None. No result matches.

The find function works just fine when I search 'div' label with class parameter.

I have also tried format like

```
.find('a[href="/pt-PT/price/bitcoin"]')
```

But nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the page is loading the currency values after the initial page load. You could try hitting ctrl+s to save the full webpage and open that file instead of using requests. If that also doesn't work, then I'm not sure where the problem is.
And if that does work, then you'll probably need to use something like selenium to get what you need

Answer (score 0):

href is an attribute of an element and hence I think you cannot find it that way.

```
def is_a_and_href_matching(element):
   is_a = element.name == a
   
   if is_a and element.has_attr(href):
      if element['href'] == "/pt-PT/price/bitcoin":
         return True
   return False

secBitcoins=root.find_all(is_a_and_href_matching)
for secBitcoin in secBitcoins:
   p = setBitcoin.find('p')
```